# Is "beguile" supposed to always be used in a bad way?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

The definitions of it, pretty much all, involve words like "trickery" and "deception".

But one legitimate definition can also be: to captivate with irresistible charm.

Nothing too bad sounding.

Comment: define:beguile   search on google simply has `charm or enchant (someone), sometimes in a deceptive way.`,   so no =)

Comment: @icy, I think a suitable answer should be more empirical than depending on what's in the dictionary. (Not regarding your answer tho)

Comment: Yes. Think of beguile as the nicer version of 'conning' someone

Comment: @Mitch, so it's bad?

Comment: @Doeser I think deciding whether a word is "good or bad" is difficult. Can you please provide some context?

Comment: @Crosscounter, I mean words like sly and cunning tend to have a negative impression on people. That's what I call bad.

Comment: "beguiling someone" is probably a little bad (but not to the degree of conning or deceiving them), "being beguiled"  may or may not be the same (it may or may not be their fault or intention), "finding someone beguiling" is usually a complement.

Comment: One could certainly be "beguiled" by a puppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely opinion, but I can't actually recall the last time I heard is used *negatively*. In recent memory, I've only seen it used as a positive, usually as an empowering feminine attribute. The notion being that the person in question is both streetwise and attractive enough to achieve whatever they want.

Most of the contexts I've seen it used in have also had mystery as a connotation, implying that the person in question is also immediately fascinating to other people, or that the source of their power is unclear.

I can't recall for certain, but I believe that the Wilson Fisk character in Netflix's Daredevil show recently called a beautiful, eloquent and foreign accented museum curator he was falling in love with, beguiling. That's the kind of scenario that the word invokes for me.

Answer (score 2):

The OED describes five different senses of the verb ***beguile***.

Two of them - numbers 4 and 5 - are very positive:

> 4. To win the attention or interest of (any one) by wiling means; to charm, divert, amuse; to wile (one) on, or into any course.
> 5. To divert attention in some pleasant way from (anything painful, or irksome); to elude the disagreeable sensation of, and so to cause to
>      pass insensibly or pleasantly; to charm away, wile away.

Comment: Into any course???  I disagree vehemently, in that being enticed into the course of eternal indebtedness by being inveigled into a few moments of pleasure is certainly not positive.

Comment: Would it not be positive if the the few moments were of infinite pleasure?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the etymology of words as well as generally perceived usage/nuance of the word.

*Beguile* comes from *guile*, which means:

> sly or cunning intelligence. (google)

If you wanted to focus on the charming or neutral tone, then consider the following synonyms:

v. fascinate, mesmerize, enthrall

adj. riveting, compelling

Answer (score 1):

"Guile" involves the befuddling and subjugation of the target's objectivity, by the beguiler, in order for the beguiler to achieve his goal.

The goal may be altruistic or nefarious, but the fact remains that, through manipulation of his target, the beguiler's aim is to cajole acceptance of his views by the target.